# ERROR Update Spring Boot: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

Currently i try to upgrade my Springboot to 3.2.2. When using springboot 3.2.2 there's no javax servlet anymore but using jakarta servlet

When run it on eclipse , i got an error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/lmsadmin] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator
```

and also

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
```

I read some post it's about JSTL dependency. But it's not working for me, Is there any solution for it ?

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.idx</groupId>
    <artifactId>lmsadmin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>lmsadmin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Jakartaa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- org json ConfigApps-->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
                
                
        <!-- Unirest -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Header Footer -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- GSON Mapping -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- apache poi -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- base.Splitter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- unbescape -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.unbescape</groupId>
            <artifactId>unbescape</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--zxing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Java melody -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamelody-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Kode Haus -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
<!--    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload2-jakarta</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Login</title>
<link rel="icon" href="<c:url value="/resources/images/favicon.ico"/>"
    type="image/x-icon" />

<link
    href="<c:url value="/resources/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link
    href="<c:url value="/resources/libs/bootstrap1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/libs/build/css/login.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link
    href="<c:url value="/resources/libs/jquery-confirm/jquery-confirm.min.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="bottom: 0; height: 1900px">
</body>
    
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"/> "></script>
<script
    src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"/> "></script>
<script
    src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/jquery-confirm/jquery-confirm.min.js"/>"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

spring-session-data-redis:1.3.1.RELEASE

This is probably outdated? Remove tag version or add 3.2.1 (lastest)

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependencies: `taglibs-standard-impl` v1.2.1 was released in 2013 so it does not belong to Jakarta EE. You should use

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You also need to check all other dependencies as well as the jsp page taglib directive: new ones are

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="jakarta.tags.xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="jakarta.tags.fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="jakarta.tags.functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="jakarta.tags.sql" %>
```